# JasperReports: Dynamically set time period in time series chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, time-series, jasperserver

I'm currently facing some problems with time periods within a time series chart.

What I want to achiveve:
- User can choose two dates; The data between those dates is going to be reported
- User can also choose the time period [Year, Month, Day] before creating report

The way I'm trying to set time period is by setting the attribute timePeriod by Parameter like this:

```xml
<timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="$P{TimePeriod}">
```

But when trying to compile, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: 
Value '$P{TimePeriod}' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration 
'[Year, Quarter, Month, Week, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Milisecond]'. 
It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

I've tried everything (e.g. changing Parameter data type, ...) but I'm always ending up getting this error. Is it even possible to set ***timePeriod*** dynamically? And how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the short answer is no. See this feature request http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport/tracker/view.php?id=4629

However, you could do a hack. Three copies of the chart

```
<band height="240">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["Year".equals($P{TimePeriod})]]></printWhenExpression>
    <timeSeriesChart>
        ...
        <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Year">
        ...
</band>
<band height="240">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["Month".equals($P{TimePeriod})]]></printWhenExpression>
    <timeSeriesChart>
        ...
        <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Month">
        ...
</band>
<band height="240">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["Day".equals($P{TimePeriod})]]></printWhenExpression>
    <timeSeriesChart>
        ...
        <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Day">
        ...
</band>
```

Sorry there isn't anything cleaner.